# NoClassFoundError in httpRequest when using Bing search api in java rest server

Tags: java, spring, maven, azure

In my spring boot project, I have a simple a rest server which I'm trying to use a library that's a wrapper for the bing search api. The library which is https://code.google.com/p/azure-bing-search-java/
depends on HTTPCore and HTTPClient, which I have listed in my pom.xml as so;

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.billylieurance.azuresearch</groupId>
    <artifactId>azure-bing-search-java</artifactId>
    <version>0.12.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
    <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
    <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.1</version>
</dependency>
```

After running mvn package, I successfully can import and use the azuresearch library, but my program breaks on the first line of code which is

```
AzureSearchWebQuery query = new AzureSearchWebQuery();
```

I get the exception: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.http.HttpRequest

Did those two HTTPCore and HTTPClient dependencies not get resolved properly? I also installed the azuresearch locally, rather than having it being picked up from the central maven repository. Could that be the cause of this exception?

Thank you very much for any help,
-Adam